# Paginate with Eloquent but without instantiation Models

Tags: laravel, optimization, eloquent

We have two Models:

- SimpleModel (id, country, code)
- ComplexRelatedModel (id, name, address)

SimpleModel has many ComplexRelatedModel, then

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    /* hasOne */
    public function complexRelatedChild()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

If we do

```
    $simples = SimpleModel
        ->with('complexRelatedChild')
        ->simplePaginate(100000 /* a lot! */);
```

And we need only do

```
foreach ($simples as $simple) {
    echo $simple->complexRelatedChild->name;
}
```

Any ComplexChild has hydratated and ready. This takes a lot of memory in my case. And we need just one field without any funciton or feature of Model.

It's possible use some data field from related object or with eloquent this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question. You want to only load one field from the `complexRelatedChild` relation to keep memory limit down?

You could do:

```
$simples = SimpleModel::with(['complexRelatedChild' => function($query){
               return $query->select(['id', 'name']);
           })
           ->simplePaginate(100000);
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
$simples = SimpleModel::with('complexRelatedChild:id,name')
           ->simplePaginate(100000);
```

However if I were you, I would try to paginate less items than `100000`.

**Update:**
You could use `chunk` or `cursor` functions to process small batches of `SimpleModel` and keep memory limit down.

```
SimpleModel::chunk(200, function ($simples) {
    foreach ($simples as $simple) {
    }
});
```

or

```
foreach (SimpleModel::cursor() as $simple) {
}
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#chunking-results) for more information

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. 

Great solution, you understand me great. (sorry for my bad English). If you think this is the best solution, great. I you have another better, I hear you :P

I need a total of resources because client get all data and sincronize with indexDB one time per day. If I paginate, the client need get page per page.

Comment: @pablorsk: I updated my answer with an other option you could try. Good luck!

Comment: your update solve my problem! the bad side is make again the SQL requests. But memory used is only 30%.